# MPI inter communication: What is the peer communicator?

Tags: mpi, communication

I'm trying to understand how to use MPI_Intercomm_create to create a communication handle from one group to another. These two groups are also written in their own C files so there is no way of one group directly accessing the other's communication handle unless I use a global variable or the like. How do I get the "peer_comm" (3rd argument of the call) for the other group? Or am I just not understanding something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MPI_Intercomm_create()` operates on communicator (e.g. `MPI_Comm`) and **not** on groups (e.g. `MPI_Group`) so let's use the right semantic here.

If you launch several binaries with the same `mpirun` command line, then they are all in `MPI_COMM_WORLD`, and this is likely what you want to use for `peer_comm`.

If you use `MPI_Comm_spawn()` in order to launch "the other binaries", then it returns your inter communicator, so you likely do not even need `MPI_Intercomm_create()`.

I strongly encourage you to write a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Not only it will help you clear some confusion, you will more likely get a precise answer once the issue is clearly stated.